# flag package in Go - do I have to always set default value?

Tags: go, command-line-arguments, flags

Is it possible not to set default value in flag package in Go? For example, in flag package you can write out the following line:

```
filename := flag.String("file", "test.csv", "Filename to cope with")
```

In the above code, I don't want to necessarily set default value, which is `test.csv` in this case, and instead always make users specify their own filename, and if it's not specified then I want to cause an error and exit the program.

One of the way I came up with is that I first check the value of `filename` after doing `flag.Parse()`, and if that value is `test.csv` then I have the program exits with the appropriate error message. However, I don't want to write such redundant code if it can be evaded - and even if it can't, I'd like to hear any better way to cope with the issue here.

You can do those kind of operations in Python's `argparse` module by the way - I just want to implement the similar thing if I can...

Also, can I implement both short and long arguments (in other words both `-f` and `-file` argument?) in flag package?

Thanks.

Comment: Please only ask one question per question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think it's idiomatic to design your flag values in such a way which implies "not present" when equal to the zero value of their respective types. For example:

```
optFile := flag.String("file", "", "Source file")
flag.Parse()
fn := *optFile
if fn == "" {
        fn = "/dev/stdin"
}
f, err := os.Open(fn)
...
```

Ad the 2nd question: IINM, the flag package *by design* doesn't distinguish between `-flag` and `--flag`. IOW, you can have both `-f` and `--file` in your flag set and write any version of `-` or `--` before both `f` and `file`. However, considering another defined flag `-g`, the flag package will *not* recognize `-gf foo` as being equvalent of `-g -f foo`.

Comment: Does the `flag` package provide a way to check whether a flag is set? I'm not talking about default values, or no values. I mean, whether a flag is present in the command line.

Comment: @Kiril, you can use the Bool option. If its value is true, then the flag is set. [Example](https://gobyexample.com/command-line-flags)

Answer (score 9):

When I have a flag that cannot have a default value I often use the value `REQUIRED` or something similar. I find this makes the `--help` easier to read.

As for why it wasn't baked in, I suspect it just wasn't considered important enough. The default wouldn't fit every need. However, the `--help` flag is similar; it doesn't fit every need, but it's good enough most of the time.

That's not to say the required flags are a bad idea. If you're passionate enough a `flagutil` package could be nice. Wrap the current `flag` api, make `Parse` return an error that describes the missing flag and add a `RequiredInt` and `RequiredIntVar` etc. If it turns out to be useful / popular it could be merged with the official `flag` package.

Comment: Thanks for the `flagutil` package. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented command argument parser.

Since there are already plenty of similar projects, I decided not to add more choices without strong impetus.

Here is an example of how it can be used, which might inspired somebody, or someone might be interested.

```
# minarg.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "self/argp"
)

func main() {
    p := argp.New(nil)
    p.Bool("continue",nil,"-v","-g")
    f := func(m, arg string) {
        switch m {
        case "__init__":
        case "__defer__":
            p.Set("server", p.GetString("-s") + ":" + p.GetString("-p"))
        default:        
            arg, _ := p.Shift()
            p.Set(m, arg)
        }
    }
    
    p.Mode(f,"__init__","__defer__","-s","-p","-nstat","-n")
    p.Default("-s","127.0.0.1", "-p","1080", "-nstat","100", "-n","5")
    p.Env("-s","SERVER", "-p","PORT")

    p.Parse()

    fmt.Println(p.Vars)
}
```

The output is

```
$ go run minarg.go
&map[-g:{false continue <nil>} -n:5 -nstat:100 -p:1080 -s:127.0.0.1 -v:{false continue <nil>} server:127.0.0.1:1080]
$ export PORT=80
$ go run minarg.go -s 0.0.0.0 -n 3 -vg
&map[-g:{true continue <nil>} -n:3 -nstat:100 -p:80 -s:0.0.0.0 -v:{true continue <nil>} server:0.0.0.0:80]
```